# OpenBMC VSCode autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code, openbmc

I'm trying to figure out if I can get some form of autocomplete working with the OpenBMC project. Not even sure where to start. What in general would the steps be?

Comment: Hey Cody, this is not a openBMC question but a purly a VScode question.
Did you every figure something out?